# Incorrect datetime value after alter table add column

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to add an int field to my table:

```
ALTER TABLE `hisData`
    ADD COLUMN `hisID2` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `hisID`;
```

But I get a mysql error:

```
SQL Error (1292): Incorrect datetime value: '1899-00-É5 É5:É5:É5' for column 'timeImported' at row 7264593
```

First off, the table is huge(obviously) but recreational(interesting statistical data) so I simply have had it on a standard HHD which started failing a bit ago and was replaced, but not before, apparently, corrupting this table a bit.

I've already ran a repair(quick first, then normal, then extended) but it has not seemed to fix this.

Obviously this going line by line is not an practical to fix this. Any ideas as to how to repair the corrupted lines?

Loosing the corrupt lines would not be a huge deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
ALTER TABLE `hisData` MODIFY `timeImported` varchar(20);
```

Then

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `hisData` MODIFY `timeImported` datetime;
```

This dropped my bad dates

Probably could have found MIN & MAX dates before altering then selected anything smaller or larger then those after switching to varchar to find most issues(not necessarily all though) but I was not concerned with data loss on this table.

Answer (score 0):

You have an incorrect datetime value in your **timeImported** column which starts with **1899-00-**. You have some options:

1. Fix it, search after **00 month** or **00 day** or **0000 year** and change it to a valid datetime

> UPDATE table_x SET timeImported='1899-01-01 00:00:00' WHERE
> timeImported LIKE '0000%' OR timeImported LIKE '%-00%'

2. **SET SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';** then error will be ignored